# CloudFront - Page Fragment Caching for React application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cloudfront

The home page of our application is mostly static content but when the user logs in, user name and some other dynamic information is shown. The user specific information is shown in a separate section.

We are using AWS CloudFront as the CDN. Could you please let me know whether it's possible to cache the static part of the page and retrive rest of the dynamic content from server?

I tried going through the cloud front docuemntation but couldn't find any references for this scenario.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes.

We need more information to understand your current setup but a typical approach could be to route:

- [www.mydomain.com/static](http://www.mydomain.com/static) -> to your static resources
- [www.mydomain.com/api](http://www.mydomain.com/api) -> to your services (dynamic content)

You can create a DNS alias mapping [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) to your CloudFront distribution then create 2 behaviours associated with the previous paths and routing the request to 2 distinct origins:

- /static -> to an S3 bucket containing your static resources
- /api -> to an API Gateway exposing your services

You can control caching at behaviour level, you can turn it off for /api

Comment: Hi Marcc, Thank you for the response. In our case, the view of the page is common for logged-in and anonymous users. The user name is displayed in the header at the top of the page. The option we are looking for is - cache the static part of the html, but dynamically load the user information.

Comment: Where do you build this user name fragment, client-side or server-side? Which framework are you using to build your page?